# Installing NVIDIA GEFORCE 750M drivers

Tags: unity, drivers, 13.10, nvidia, graphics

Is there any way to install NVIDIA GEFORCE 750M drivers for Ubuntu?

Right now `Intel Haswell Mobile` is used for graphics. Is this ok? Can I get better performance by installing NVIDIA drivers?

> [image]

I remember that last time when I installed something related to that, my Unity was broken. After uninstalling them Unity worked again.

Comment: Most possibly nvidia optimus system, see - [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing the tested NVIDIA drivers for Ubuntu:

> [image]

I can see the following details:

> [image]

So, GeForce GT 750M /PCIe/SSE2 driver is installed.

---

BTW, I switched again on the open source driver. NVIDIA drivers had important issues (overheating and sometimes the entire screen was freezing).

After applying changes and rebooting Ubuntu started in low graphics mode. I pressed <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. I deleted the following file:

```
 sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Then I restarted the PC:

```
 sudo reboot
```

My machine uses again the open source driver and it works fine. If you don't have big issues with the open source driver, I really recommend not to switch on the closed source one.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the drivers from NVIDIA website worked for me. just download the latest stable version for your card [here](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-uk).

Now, the only problem is the graphic server have to be down to install them. Save the file .run in your desktop and switch to a tty with Ctrl + Alt + F6

Log in and type the following commands:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
chmod +x NVIDIA*.run 
sudo ./NVIDIA*.run
```

Follow the on-screen instructions. If it tells you something like "pre install script for your distribution failed" that's normal, just chose yes. When it's done, reboot with:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Note that I've used the * but you could use the full name of the file, which depends on what version you download. I'd recommend you to use the latest stable, right now 334.21.

Comment: Do I get updates installing them this way? Isn't there any available PPA?

Comment: No, it doesn't get updates. I've tried many PPA's but this is the best solution I've found. It's not a big deal for me anyway, checking NVIDIA's website every  now and then.

Comment: I will install them later today and then I will give you feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Just one thing. If you have problems making them work, to remove them you'll need to run /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall as sudo. Don't try to install other drivers trough the package manager before removing these ones, because they'll conflict. Good luck!

Comment: I have installed the drivers following the steps you indicated. After restarting Unity crashes (even after a fresh Ubuntu reinstall). And yes, I downloaded the correct driver: NVIDIA GEFORCE 700 Series, GT 750M Linux 64 bit. After uninstalling the drivers, the problem persists. Now, I reinstalled Ubuntu 13.10 again. What can I do?

Comment: The only other option I know is install the free opensource drivers, nouveau with sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau but never worked for me. You can give it a try.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13673/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-darent)

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a try to 352.41 driver?

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

I've the same processor, graphic card and memory (maybe same laptop? :D ). Neither bumblebee nor nvidia-331 made the trick for me, so I'm about to try 352.41 as suggested on Nvida web site.

I'll tell you later if it gives some help or not.